# Crossfilter Dimension limitations in the document say 8 or 16 or 32, its confusing

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Crossfilter dimensions documents say `Creating more than 8 dimensions, and more than 16 or 32 dimensions, introduces additional overhead` i'm sort of confused with the statement? Could you please clarify this?

The overhead is when we create more than 8 or 16 or 32 dimensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an implementation "detail" (btw, I don't think crossfilter works with more than 32 dimensions).

I wouldn't take it as a hard limit and just read it as "the more dimensions, the slower it gets". Based on the size of your dataset, you might be fine with dozen of dimensions.

The bigger the dataset and the more dimensions, the slower it becomes, and if filtering when clicking on a graph takes "too long", dc is loosing its magic. If it becomes too unresponsive, you have too many dimensions ;)

It also depends who are the user(s) of what you are building: if all the users are on new laptops and modern browsers, if you are happy with the speed, it's going to be fine.

If you develop for a public website, you need to test on smartphones, what works fine on your laptop probably doesn't as well on an old android.

Comment: Exactly. (Also, the community fork, `crossfilter2` in NPM, allows an unlimited number of dimensions. Woohoo!)